# Typescript: Cannot infer known return type of class instance method

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm new to generics and trying to create generic methods to "hydrate" plain Javascript objects as class instances and then "dehydrate" them again to their original plain object type. Each class has a `.toObject()` method that returns the same type as is used in the constructor for instantiation (see `MyClass` below).

I am able to write a generic function for hydrating plain objects, but for *de*hydration I cannot figure out how to generically refer to the returntype of the `.toObject()` method (each class has a different return type for this method).

The first function in the code below is my dehydrator, and it is used in the `.toObject` call at the end. How can I change the typing of this generic function so that the types are automatically inferred instead of having to be specified?

**Edit:** I edited too many things at once when preparing the sample. It turns out that passing the generic function directly to `.map()` does not work, while writing out an arrow function *does* work. This is a totally fine solution, though I'd love to know why this is the case or if there is a trick to make it work.

```js
export function dehydrate<DehydratedObject,HydratedObject extends {toObject:()=>DehydratedObject}>(fancyObject:HydratedObject){
  return fancyObject.toObject();
}

export function hydrate<DehydratedObject,TargetClass extends new (object:DehydratedObject)=>InstanceType<TargetClass>>(plainObject:DehydratedObject,targetClass:TargetClass){
  return new targetClass(plainObject);
}

interface SourceData {
  name: string,
  children: SourceData[]
}

interface TransformedData extends Omit<SourceData,'children'>{
  children: MyClass[]
}

class MyClass{

  #data: TransformedData;

  constructor(sourceData:SourceData){
    this.#data = {
      ...sourceData,
      // I do not need to specify classes when calling the 'hydrate' generic,
      // which is perfect.
      children: sourceData.children.map(child=>hydrate(child,MyClass))
    };
  }

  toObject(): SourceData{
    return {
      ...this.#data,
      // QUESTION: This does not work, but if I replaced `dehydrate`
      //           with a full arrow function `child=>dehydrate(child)`
      //           it *does* work.
      children: this.#data.children.map(dehydrate)
    }
  }
}
```

*(As an aside, these generic typings are super verbose -- is there a way to store a generic as a re-usable type?)*

Comment: If I copy and paste your code in the typescript playground, then remove the `<SourceData,MyClass>` from the last line so it reads simply `dehydrate(child)`, then it already correctly infers the type of `dehydrate` as `function dehydrate<SourceData, MyClass>(fancyObject: MyClass): SourceData`. So I think it already works exactly like you expect it to. If you are getting a different result please provide a link to a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) that shows the problem.

Comment: Interesting. I had originally be using `this.#data.children.map(dehydrate)`, which did not work. To provide types I filled out the arrow function, but I didn't check to see if the full arrow function *without* types would work. You are correct that it does.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. I'm not sure why that is, to be honest.